# How to populate the page via JQuery after I have the json returned

Tags: php, jquery

Ok so i have the json object returned back from my script and I have all the data but how do I put it on the page. Here is what i have so far

I have a php page which has a loop like this

```
<div class="main-blue">
<div class="blue-items">
<?php foreach ($related as $row_r) { ?>
<div class="item-blue">
<div class="image left">
<img src="<?php print $row_r['image'] == "" ? "css/images/blue-png2.png" : "css/images/{$row_r['image']}" ?>" alt="" />
```

As you can see the Php loop is looping through the array $related which has lots of products. I have an ajax call that can change the data in this array and regenerate the page. I have the new data from a getjson call

```
 $.getJSON('function.php?type=piz&count=5', function(data) {
 $(data).each(function(key, value) {
   console.log(value);
   });
});
```

How do i recreate the page using the new data

Comment: what does the json returned look like?

Comment: each element is an object

Object { name="LENOVO - SMALL FORM PC",  more...}

then i click on it in firebug and i get the attributes for each like the price and the image and description

Comment: Where's the rest of the `foreach()` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're talking about is client side templating.  Rick Strahl has a good write up on the concept: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/509108.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your JS.
$.getJSON('function.php?type=piz&count=5', function(data) {
     $(data).each(function(key, value) {
       $('#contentHere').html(value);
       });
    });

your html

```
<div id="contentHere"></div>
```

Comment: Won't this code just replace the contents of the "contentHere" element over and over and over again and just leave it with the last element's value? I know what you are driving at here, but this code, as it stands, will just confuse the OP further.

Comment: this is basically just a short explanation. if he'll get confused, then he'll learn. I'm not here to spoon feed.